# Trouble starting apache with two virtual hosts, 2 ip's and 2 ssl's

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

In Apache 2.2.22 I am attempting to run two virtual hosts with two IP addys and two SSL certs. I have nothing regarding listening to ports or NameVirtualHost in any other configuration files other than the files that configure the virtual hosts. In the process of getting this to work I would like to have the minimum amount of code necessary.

In the sites-available directory I have site1.com config file:

```
NameVirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80
Listen 1.1.1.1:80
Listen 1.1.1.1:443

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ServerAdmin me@site1.com
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.site1.com/ [R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/j/site1/public

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site1.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle_site1.crt

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/j/site1/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/j/site1/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If site1.com is the only site that is enabled, the server starts fine. When I enable site2.com I run into trouble. `Sudo apachectl configtest` results in `Syntax OK` but a restart of apache results in `(99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address 2.2.2.2:8080 no listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs Action 'start' failed.` Here's the content of site2.com:

```
NameVirtualHost 2.2.2.2:8080
Listen 2.2.2.2:8080
Listen 2.2.2.2:4430

<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:8080>
    ServerAdmin me@site2.com
    ServerName  site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !4430
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.site2.com/ [R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:4430>
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /home/j/site2/public

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site2.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site2.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle_site2.crt

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/j/site2/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/j/site2/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

Results for netstat -lpn less udp6:

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 1.1.1.1:80         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7187            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 1.1.1.1:443        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55363         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::7187                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 1.1.1.1:123        0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     169974   -                   /tmp/passenger.1.0.32045/generation-0/spawn-server/socket.32055.19978820
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2823     -                   @/tmp/fam-root-
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     180580   -                   /tmp/passenger.1.0.32045/generation-0/backends/ruby.ui0IFvdXouP5Ukb3zZo2fiLBEJOgc5835cbcGK93fhrs5ogoitaPfi1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10547    -                   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     106      -                   @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     182366   -                   /var/run/apache2/cgisock.32045
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     395      -                   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     168      -                   /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12724    -                   /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     181619   -                   /tmp/passenger.1.0.32045/generation-0/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     181621   -                   /tmp/passenger.1.0.32045/generation-0/spawn-server/socket.32053.32793072
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     181640   -                   /tmp/passenger.1.0.32045/generation-0/logging.socket
```

UPDATE:

grep -r Listen /etc/apache2 produces no reference to Listen on port 8080 other than what is mentioned above.

UPDATE:

Per Jenny D's suggestion below, ifconfig -a produces the following:

```
dummy0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:fc:55:b0:9e:80  
          BROADCAST NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:70:34:84  
          inet addr:50.116.59.14  Bcast:50.116.59.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fe70:3484/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::f03c:91ff:fe70:3484/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:69078 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41852 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:16773617 (16.7 MB)  TX bytes:69148409 (69.1 MB)
          Interrupt:76 

gre0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-34-84-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:1476  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ip6gre0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:1448  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ip6tnl0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:1452  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ip_vti0   Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
          NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3487 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3487 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:62766 (62.7 KB)  TX bytes:62766 (62.7 KB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tunl0     Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr   
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `2.2.2.2` address exists on your system, right? And nothing else is listening on that port?

Comment: Should `<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:80>` be `<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:8080>` there?

Comment: @EtanReisner Good catch. That might be very well the issue.

Comment: thanks,... that is not the issue tho. typo on my part. see the error msg. +1 for catching it tho.

Comment: Yeah. I couldn't imagine how that would cause that error message but @NathanC had taken the simple suggestion for that error. =)

Comment: @NathanC, Linode gave me an additional ip that is set up in the DNA manager in A/AAAA Records.

Comment: @Jay Post the results of `netstat -lpn`

Comment: @Jay  `NameVirtualHost` is deprecated. I'm gussing port `8080` is being held by some process.  Can your run these commands?  `netstat -tanup`  and  `lsof -i :8080`

Comment: netstat results above. lsof -i :8080 produces nothing.

Comment: Show your network config (e.g. `ifconfig -a`).

Answer (score 1):

This error can be caused by having two `Listen` directives for the same IP address/port combination.

Since your `netstat` shows nothing listening on port 8080, I strongly suspect this is your issue.

Try `grep -r Listen /etc/apache2` to find them.

Comment: Already did that. There is no Listen directive for any ip on port 8080 other than what is indicated above.

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe it. It was the firewall. Had to add the ports.